# RewriteMap Directive (permanent or temp redirect?)

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

This may sound like a silly question and I'm probably mixing apple with oranges, but please bear with me.

I'm reading the documentation here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#mapfunc

It says when using an external .txt file the format is a simple key/value pair example:

> fromHere.html toHere.html

^ I'd like to confirm that the above would create a temp 302 redirect (that browsers won't aggressively cache), or may be I can indicate the type of redirect to be used (301/302) in the actual RewriteRule in the htaccess file? (if so how?)

Currently I use the following syntax inside the .htaccess file itself

> Redirect 302 fromHere.html toHere.html

Is the above syntax allowed in the external .txt file?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite doesn't equal redirect! From [Using RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html):

> The `RewriteMap` directive defines an external function which can be
>   called in the context of `RewriteRule` or `RewriteCond` directives to
>   perform rewriting that is too complicated, or too specialized to be
>   performed just by regular expressions.

The type of the rewrite is defined as a *flag* in [`RewriteRule` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), syntax:

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

Most of the rewriting is done silently on server-side, without the browser even knowing about it. For external `302` redirect you'll need flag `R=302`:

> `redirect|R[=code]`
>
> Forces an external redirect, optionally with the specified HTTP status code.

The [`Redirect` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) you are using in your `.htaccess` is related to `mod_alias` instead of `mod_rewrite` and has nothing to do with `RewriteMap`s.